# Continuous function on the plane to real line.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity

I know a proof to show that the open disc is an open set in which I show the inclusion of a neighborhood into the disc. But a much shorter answer would be to find a continuous function from the plane onto the real line such that the open disk centered at say, the origin, is mapped to an open interval. I seek an example of such a function. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  x + \mathrm{i} y \mapsto x  \text{.}  $$
$$  x + \mathrm{i} y \mapsto y  \text{.}  $$
$$  x + \mathrm{i} y \mapsto x+y  \text{.}  $$

These aren't quite enough, though...

You can use that the continuous preimage of an open set is open and consider instead
$$  |\cdot |: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} : r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta} \mapsto r  \text{.}  $$
Then recall that $[0,1)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (in the subspace topology) and its (full) preimage is the unit disk.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Making the co domain the positive real ray, instead of the entire axis, does the job. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x,y) = x + y$$

Here the image of the open disk is $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} )$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

**This should have been a comment**

Note first that you want a continouus function such that the preimage of the unit interval is the disc - images are not going to help you.

Note secondly that the strategy is ill-advised - you'll need to show that your given function is actually continouus; this will almost certainly be more difficult than showing your claim directly.

This brings me to my third point: What's your definition of the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2 $ and why is your claim not obvious from the defnition?

Comment: Thanks but with due respect, your answer isn't an answer and neither helpful. I was trying to find an alternative approach to a question that is very common. It was of my own accord I realized that I can use the fact that inverse image of an open set, for a continuous function is open. Also, I am allowed to use continuous functions without proving their continuity. Lastly, I do know point set topology, but this question was on a complex variables quiz, where it is not an obvious claim.

Comment: Sorry if the answer sounded rude, I did not want to take anything away from your strategy (which certainly works well in the context of other topologies, such as the Zariski one). 

Still I want to point out that specifying the continuous functions on the plane is hard; I cannot really come up with a definition which is not making your proof essentially circular.

I'm unhappy if my answer wasn't helpful to you, but I invite you to think about it again.